# I am confused on how to use the grid templates to align images in a segment

Tags: html, css

I am doing an assignment for my school. I am stuck here, please help! [This is the segment that I need to built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVuJh.jpg)

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MHM Travels</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mhmtravel.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ee91cd0c31.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <div class="travel-header">
                <img src="Images/Group-40071.png" alt="" width="80">
                <h1>MHM <span class="travel-span">Travel</span></h1>
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <li><a href=""><span class="travel-span">Home</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Packages</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Testimonial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="header-section">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>Explore Your Travel</h2>
            <p>Have the best time in your life. Traveling is part of the experience of the goodness in life.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="travel-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Where go" class="input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="When" class="input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Select Type" class="input">
            <button class="search"><span class="fontawesome"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></span> Find Now</button>
        </div>

    </section>
    <section class="second-section">
        <div class="popular-tours">
        <h3>Our Popular Tours</h3>
        <p>Roam around with bengali people's guide. We have some of the most exciting tours for you. Our tours are cost friendly and we provide free trips</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Dive into Bengal's culture with expert local guides, leading you off the beaten path for an authentic Bengali experience.</li>
            <li>Enjoy affordable tours designed for all budgets, ensuring you explore Bengal without financial strain or compromising on quality.</li>
            <li>Experience the generosity of free trips to selected destinations, making travel accessible and promoting responsible tourism in Bengal.</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Experience the allure of Bengal like never before with our guided tours. Immerse yourself in the rich culture and traditions, explore on a budget without sacrificing quality, and even enjoy the added bonus of free trips to selected destinations. Let us be your guide to the wonders of Bengal, where every journey is an adventure worth remembering.</p>
        <button class="read-more">Read More</button></div>
        <div class="img-second">
            <img src="Images/Rectangle 4.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </section>
    <Section>
        <Div class="theta"><p id="Maldives">Maldives</p>
        <p id="indonesia">Indonesia</p></Div>
        <Div class="alpha"><p id="srilanka">Srilanka</p>
        <p id="north-America">North America</p>
        <p id="kashmir">Kashmir</p></Div>
        <Div class="beta"><p id="bangladesh">Bangladesh</p>
        <p id="bandarban">Bandarban</p></Div>
    </Section> 

    

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my css code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:wght@400;800&display=swap');


* {
    font-family: 'Mulish', sans-serif;
}

body{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

header {
    padding: 0;
}

.travel-span {
    color: #FF5400;
}


.nav-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
}

.travel-header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-bar img {
    padding-right: 4px;
    height: auto;
}

.nav-bar h1 {
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 36px;
}

nav {
    width: 50%;
}

.navigation {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    gap: 40px;
}

.navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: var(--Dark-02, #424247);
}

.header-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(Images/Group-13.png);
    background-size: cover;
    width: 1170px;
    height: 500px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    padding: 50px 0;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 16px;
    margin: 50px auto;

}

.title h2 {
    font-size: 64px;
    font-weight: 800;

}

.title p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.travel-form {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 16px;
    gap: 24px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / 31%);
}

.input {
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #FFF;
}

.fontawesome {
    padding-right: 8px;
}

.search,
.fontawesome {
    color: #fff;
}

.search {
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #FF5400;
}

.second-section {
    display: flex;
    gap: 70px;
    padding: 120px;   
}

.second-section h3 {
    color: #131318;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin: 0;   
}

.popular-tours{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 24px;
}

.popular-tours ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 16px;
}

.read-more{
    padding: 12px 30px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #FF5400;
    color: #FFF;    
}

.theta, .alpha, .beta{
    display: grid;
}

.theta{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.alpha{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 3fr);
}
.beta{
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

#maldives {
    background-image: url(../Images/Rectangle-5.png);
}



@media only screen and (max-width:576px) {
    .header-section {
        width: 460px;
        height: 600px;
        border-radius: 16px;
        background-image: url(Images/Group-13.png);
        background-size: cover;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    nav {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav-bar h1 {
        padding-left: 0;
    }


    .travel-header {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .title {
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: 800;
    }

    .travel-form {
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 10px;
        gap: 10px;
    }

    .second-section{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 2em;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .img-second{
        background: cover;
        /* padding: 37px 20px; */
        margin: 37px 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }

}
```

Still, I am not able to setup the segment as above and the highest I can reach is like this; [this is as far as I could achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDBy0.png)

I was trying to use grid template colums property for the class. But It's not taking background image from css. What could be the reason here and how to best approach this and complete this segment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specify right css id. This is your css

```
#maldives {
    background-image: url(../Images/Rectangle-5.png);
}
```

And this is your id in HTML

```
<p id="Maldives">Maldives</p>
```

You should css for `#Maldives`, not for `#maldives`

```
#Maldives {
    background-image: url("https://i.natgeofe.com/k/f576c284-661a-4046-ba51-fa95699e1a8b/hawaii-beach.png");
    background-size: cover;
    /* background-color: #424247; */
}
```

[image: result]